# Very simple react destructuring issue with a custom hook

Tags: reactjs

I'm amazed that I can't solve this myself, but I'm having a basic issue here. Essentially I just want to destructure the `user` variable in the `useSetWelcome` hook to prevent the use of verbose chaining such as `user.user.email` - for instance, `const { email } = user` does not work and instead needs user.user.

I tried changing from `const useSetWelcome = user => {` to `const useSetWelcome = ({ user }) => {`, but that results in an infinite loop.

Where am I going wrong here? My code demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b1jroe

And the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const joe = {
  name: 'Joe',
  email: 'joe@bloggs.com'
};

// const useSetWelcome = ({ user }) => { // infinite loop problem
const useSetWelcome = user => {
  const [name, setName] = useState(null);
  const [welcomeMsg, setWelcomeMsg] = useState('No user detected');
  // const { email } = user; // needs user.user
  // console.log('user', user);
  // console.log('{user}', { user });
  // console.log('user.email', user.email); // should be joe@bloggs.com
  // console.log('email', email); // should be joe@bloggs.com
  console.log('user?.user?.email', user?.user?.email); // works

  if (user.name) {
    setName(user.name);
    setWelcomeMsg('welcome ' + user.name);
  }

  return { name, welcomeMsg };
};

const App = () => {
  // const [user, setUser] = useState(joe); // joe or {joe}? and why?
  const [user, setUser] = useState(joe);
  console.log('state user', user);

  const toggleLogin = user => {
    if (user) {
      setUser(null);
    } else {
      setUser(joe);
    }
  };

  const loginMsg = user ? 'Logout' : 'Login';

  const Welcome = user => {
    const { name, welcomeMsg } = useSetWelcome(user);
    return (
      <p>
        {welcomeMsg} {name}
      </p>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Welcome user={user} />
      <button onClick={() => toggleLogin(user)}>{loginMsg}</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, `<Welcome />` is a component. A component receives only one parameter, `props`. So, when you write this: `const Welcome = user => {`, its actually `const Welcome = props => {`.

Long story short, change this line to `const Welcome = ({ user }) => {` (so you destruct `user` from `props`) and it will work.

P.S.: You're getting an infinite loop because inside your `useSetWelcome` hook, you have this condition:

```
if (user.name) {
  setName(user.name)
}
```

When you use `setName`, the entire hook rerenders, and the condition is tested again. Again, `user.name` will exist, and `setName` will get called again, and again, and forever. To achieve what I think you intended to, you have to improve the condition to something like this:

```
if (user.name && user.name !== name) {
    setName(user.name);
    setWelcomeMsg('welcome ' + user.name);
}
```

Comment: that's an interesting explanation - didn't actually realise that you had to destructure if from there and that it'd just be props. But there's an infinite loop with your solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1ogqnr - why does this occur?